# What does this common SPI function do?

Tags: arduino, spi

I see this function in Arduino scripts using SPI: ISR (SPI_STC_vect). I am familiar with C but this doesn't seem to follow - it looks like a function though there is no return type definition, and the argument doesn't make sense. I am new to SPI and cannot find much/any documentation online. Other functions which run during an interrupt are called using attachInterrupt, however this doesn't seem to be called anywhere.

Comment: Read documentation mentioned below.  And note also that different Arduino parts have different ISRs available, and different vectors for them.  Refer to the datasheet **for your exact part** to get the right information for your design.

Answer (score 2):

[`ISR()`](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__interrupts.html#gad28590624d422cdf30d626e0a506255f) is a macro that introduces an interrupt handler.

`SPI_STC_vect` is a Serial Transfer Complete interrupt vector.

See [here](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__interrupts.html) for complete documentation, including the list of available interrupt vectors.